# UINavigationBar titleview image not aligned with the UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar

My logo was looking to small in the default UINavigationBar, so I increased the height to 67 by overriding

```
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size
{
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 67);
return newSize;
}
```

I added a 2x image of size 266x130 in the `- (void)viewDidLoad` using

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];
```

But my title logo is not aligned with the NavigationBar.

[image: Screenshot]

I just wanted to know why the title view is behaving weird with custom height. I did not have any issue while adding image as title view to the standard UINavigationBar.

Also is this the right way to override UINavigationBar for custom height? Are there any other methods to do the same?

Comment: :Your image size is large. Resize the image decrease the height of the image. I m not sure but try this

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this or something like it?

```
  float positionOffset = ...;
 [UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:positionOffset forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

There's also [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007519-CH3-SW58), if that doesn't immediately work.

Comment: How do I obtain the position offset value?

Comment: You can put any number you want in there. You can calculate it exactly (or not, since its an offset, not your absolute choice), or you can just eyeball it; I would guess it should be (- 10 points).

Comment: I was looking for a more standard way to align the title view. Anyways will try this for time being.

Comment: Let me know if it works... Nothing is standard when it comes to customizing navigation bars.